# Formation of material balance equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, physical-chemistry

What should I do with a1 after forming the material balance equation and how do I find Q baSed on that i have already tried that Qin = Qout at steady state but I don’t know what to do next?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj7ky.png

Comment: What subject is this related to? Can you give more background information?

Comment: Chemical engineering

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.